# Include perl module from a different location

Tags: perl

my problem is as follows

1. I have the lib in location ./abc/def/lib
2. I am using it in path ./abc/xyz/lib/tuv/abc.pm

I am running the code from a different location altogether
which is something like ./abc/xyz/blah1/blah2/../../ . I'm running the code here.

I have created env params

```
setenv def ./abc/def 
setenv xyz ./abc/xyz
```

I tried the below solutions

1. `Begin { push(@INC, $ENV{def}."/lib" ) }`
   Along with the providing the path for other libraries i used
   use lib $ENV{xyz}."/lib"

   This solution didn't work. I get the error saying the library in ./abc/def/lib
   is not included.
2. I tried the FindBin

   ```
   # for the libs present in ./abc/def/lib
   use FindBin;
   use lib "$FindBin::Bin/../../";
   use mylib::abc;
   use mylib::def;
   ```

(I tried giving the path also of root from where to start looking..in FindBin)

I tried using different combinations but not sure why it doesn't work.
Can someone point out what i am doing wrong or is my understanding of FindBin wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `FindBin` module is the best fit for your needs. The important thing to remember is that `$FindBin::Bin` refers to the directory that contains *the script*. So when you refer to it ...

```
use lib $FindBin::Bin . '/../../etc';
```

the '/../..' path must describe the path from the script directory to the lib directory.

The other important thing to take into consideration is the error message.  It will start with `Can't locate Your/Module/Name.pm` but will then go on to list all the directories in `@INC` - the library search path.  Check this list of directories to make sure it includes the lib path you intended to add.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Grant McLean for the explanation. It clarified my understanding of FindBin now. Your answer was helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You don't say what problems you're having. Just saying you're "not sure why it doesn't work" isn't really helpful. I assume you're getting a "Can't locate [some module] in @INC" error.

There are three (recommended) ways to change the value of `@INC`. Each have their uses.

- Inside a program, you can use `use lib`
- From the command line (or in a shebang), you can use `-I`
- In your shell environment, you can set `PERL5LIB`

In all these cases, the new directories will be added to the start of `@INC`, so these directories will be searched before the standard library directories.

You can also manually manipulate `@INC`. Note that in order for manual manipulation of `@INC` to have any effect on `use` statements in your code, they will need to be executed in a `BEGIN` block (as `use` statements are executed at compile time).  It looks like you have tried that too, but that you used `Begin` rather than `BEGIN` - which wouldn't work.

If you are running your program from a location that is completely unrelated to the directories where the libraries are kept, then [FindBin](https://metacpan.org/pod/FindBin) is likely to be of limited use. FindBin is useful where the location of the executable file and the libraries are closely related (for example the executable file is in `./bin` and the libraries is in `./lib`).

It also seems that you are trying to adjust `@INC` from within a library (`./abc/xyz/lib/tuv/abc.pm`). Note that FindBin will not set `$FindBin::Bin` to this directory. `$FindBin::Bin` is always set to the directory that contains the executable file which is running.

Without knowing more about the actual paths that you are using (you have only given relative paths in your examples) it's hard to know for sure what the best approach is. But I think that in your situation I'd be setting `PERL5LIB` to the absolute path of your extra libraries.

Comment: Sorry @Dave Cross. I forgot to mentioned the error. Yes , i got the error you mentioned. Thank you for your detailed explanation. This gave me better understanding of when to use FindBin and a better perspective also. Thank you for your time.